# Select statement with count

Tags: sql, count

I want to count the number of ABC group using id.

```
SELECT group, count(id) as total FROM `user` WHERE group=`ABC`;
```

What's wrong?
Many thanks.

Comment: I will ask you the same, what is wrong?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? And what error are you getting?

Comment: That is invalid SQL - you need to include the column `"group"` in a `group by` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Include the columns in the select list in `group by` clause when using aggregate functions.

```
SELECT group, count(id) as total FROM user 
WHERE group=`ABC`
GROUP BY group
```

Else simply get the count with out using other columns in the select statement.

```
SELECT count(id) as total FROM user 
WHERE group=`ABC`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT group, count(id) as total FROM `user`
     group by group having group like 'ABC';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get COUNT of users, who has the "group" field = "ABC"

```
SELECT count(id) as total FROM user WHERE group='ABC';
```

Also, it's better to avoid using SQL keywords in column names (GROUP is an SQL keyword)